# Login ,Signup in same page django(multiple forms authentication)?I'am able to signup ... Why is it showing invalid credential in meassage while log in

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-login

I am able to signin but not able to log in it shows invalid credentials

VIEWS.PY

```
        if request.method=='POST':
            
            if request.POST.get('submit')=='sign_up':
                
                username=request.POST.get('name')
                email=request.POST.get('email')
                password=request.POST.get('password')
                
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():                             # Condition for same email id if already exists
                    messages.warning(request,'Email already exists')
                else:
                    user =User(email=email,password=password,username=username)
                    user.set_password(password)                                             #since raw passwords are not saved therefore needs to set in this method
                    user.save()
                    messages.success(request,'User has been registered successfully')      #Dispalys message that user has been registerd 
                return redirect('login')
    
            elif request.POST.get('loginsubmit')=='sign_in':
                email = request.POST['email']
                password = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect ('/')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request,'Invalid credentials')
            # print(email,password,username)
        
            
        return render (request,'login.html')`
```

LOGIN.html

```
//<section id="form"><!--form-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                            <form method="POST" action="login">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="validationDefault01" name="email" required>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="validationDefault02" name="password" required>
                                <span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                    Keep me signed in
                                </span>
                                <button type="submit" name='loginsubmit' value='sign_in' class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                            </form>
                        </div><!--/login form-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <h2 class="or">OR</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
      
    <!-- language: lang-html -->
    
        {% block body %}
    
        <body>
            {% for message in messages %}
        <section>
            <div class=" container alert alert-{{message.tags}} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <strong>Message!</strong> {{message}}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </div>
        </section>
           {% endfor %}
           
          
    
    
            <section id="form"><!--form-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                                <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                                <form method="POST" action="login">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="validationDefault01" name="email" required>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="validationDefault02" name="password" required>
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                        Keep me signed in
                                    </span>
                                    <button type="submit" name='loginsubmit' value='sign_in' class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div><!--/login form-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <h2 class="or">OR</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="signup-form"><!--sign up form-->
                                <h2>New User Signup!</h2>
                                <form method="POST" action="login">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="validationDefault05" name="name" required>
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="validationDefault03" name="email" required>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="validationDefault04" name="password" required>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name='submit' value='sign_up'>Signup</button>
                                </form>
                            </div><!--/sign up form-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section><!--/form-->
            
        </body>
        {% endblock %}
    
    <!-- end snippet -->
    
                        <div class="signup-form"><!--sign up form-->
                            <h2>New User Signup!</h2>
                            <form method="POST" action="login">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="validationDefault05" name="name" required>
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="validationDefault03" name="email" required>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="validationDefault04" name="password" required>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name='submit' value='sign_up'>Signup</button>
                            </form>
                        </div><!--/sign up form-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!--/form-->//`
```

URLS.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *
    
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        # path('register',views.register, name='register'),
        path('login',views.login_user, name='login'),
    ]
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to explain here. What is the error you are getting? Please follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to format your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

> it shows invalid credentials

Because your `authenticate()` returns None

`authenticate()` takes username and password by default for the authentication and you are providing email and password for authentication. If you want to authenticate from email and password write your own custom authentication backend.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class CustomEmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

After that point your custom authentication in `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.CustomEmailBackend']
```

Also make your email filed `unique=True`

Answer (score 0):

By default authentication is done by username field of the auth user model,
you need to set username_field to email field in the auth user model.Your auth user model should be like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    **fields**
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```